# How to change format of Date into the form 02-Jun-2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I am filling my Grid from database. On `RowEditing` event I am fetching data from grid to TextBox. This is the code that I am using

```
txtDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["BuyDate"]).ToShortDateString();
```

This gives me date in `02-06-2015` format but I want to display date in `02-Jun-2015` format.

Comment: Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["BuyDate"]).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")

Comment: the first link to msdn when you do google.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `ToString` method and pass there the format you want.

```
txtDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["BuyDate"]).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

At the bottom of [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you will find also other useful formats.

Answer (score 3):

From [`DateTime.ToShortDateString` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The value of the current `DateTime` object is formatted using the
>   pattern defined by the [`DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortDatePattern` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern(v=vs.110).aspx)
>   associated with the current thread culture.

That means, your `CurrentCulture`'s `ShortDatePattern` is `dd-MM-yyyy`. If you want [abbreviated month name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.abbreviatedmonthnames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of your `CurrentCulture`, you can use [`MMM` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MMM_Specifier) instead.

```
txtDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["BuyDate"])
                      .ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

Remember, if your `CurrentCulture` is not *english-based* one, this `MMM` specifier will generate a different name than `Jun`. In such a case, you can provider an english-based `IFormatProvider` (like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) as a second parameter in `ToString` method like;

```
txtDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["BuyDate"])
                      .ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the DateTime format, box the string into DateTime and use the the formatting string via ToString(), like :

```
txtDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["BuyDate"]).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

visit this link of MSDN for complete details:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this

```
 Convert.ToDateTime(YourDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"]).ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
```

OR

```
Convert.ToDateTime(YourDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"]).ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy");
```

Or what ever you want

Comment: @SonerGönül I just tried to explain how to change formats(that what the OP asked about). Not meant to give details of the right formats

Answer (score 0):

See here: [examples](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) how to format DateTimes.

In your case `dd-MMM-yyyy` wold be the correct pattern.

As mentioned, you don't have to use `string.Format()`, the `.ToString()` does also allow to pass the pattern.

**Please note**, that you should also consider to keep the information as DateTime (not string) and format it in a Binding (if you are using DataBinding) that would sepparate the view from the underlying data

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
txtDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["BuyDate"]).ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
```

Comment: This is **not** what OP wants.

Comment: Yes it gives "11 Jun 2015" as result, Or can use .ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") for the exact pattern